# Rails 4.2 uniquenness.rb:55 in find_finder_class_for error undefined method `abstract_class?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, abstract-class

I am updating the rails from v4.0.13 to v4.2.11.3 and when I am going to save some object, the following error appears:

rails console:
`User.new.save`

Error:
NoMethodError: undefined method `abstract_class?' for nil:NilClass from /.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb:55:in` block in find_finder_class_for'

This is method in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb:

```
     def find_finder_class_for(record)
       class_hierarchy = [record.class]

       while class_hierarchy.first != @klass
         class_hierarchy.unshift(class_hierarchy.first.superclass)
       end

       class_hierarchy.detect { |klass| !klass.abstract_class? }
     end
```

Someone for help me?

Comment: This means that you traversed the full stack of class hierarchy and ended up at `BasicObject` e.g. `[nil,BasicObject,Object,...]` since `BasicObject.superclass #=> nil` the loop stops because then `class_hierarchy.first == @klass` if `@klass == nil`. Can you post your User class and the validation that is causing this?

Comment: I'm always a little dubious when I see relatively new software (ruby 2.6.6) mixed with ancient software (rails 4.2). According to [this](https://www.hmallett.co.uk/2018/08/ruby-and-ruby-on-rails-version-compatibility/), the latest version of ruby supported on rails 4.2 was 2.4. Did you really _just_ upgrade rails from 4.0 to 4.2, or did you also upgrade a plethora of other things (including the ruby version) when you started encountering this error?

Comment: @TomLord yes, i am updating a multitude of project gems. In this update, this issue with validation is happening. I saw that the method doesn't take the initialize, and therefore the class_hierarchy variable is null. What better solution? Rewrite the method?

Comment: @RodrigodeSá My point is that if you've updated multiple things simultaneously, then we can't be sure which update actually triggered the problem. If you revert the last update, and ONLY (!!!!!) update rails from 4.0-->4.2, then do you see the above error?